# Python: Is it possible to unpack a sequence type inline in a "with" statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way to do inline unpacking in a with statement in python?

Right now, I have a custom context manager that returns a `sqlalchemy` `row` object, and the associated `session` needed to potentially delete it as a 2-tuple, and handles the necessary database manipulations on context exit:

```
with self.row_sess_context(dbid=relid) as tup:
    row, sess = tup

    ...[manipulation code]...
```

Now, it seems to me like it'd be particularly "pythonic" to be able to do something like:

```
    with self.row_sess_context(dbid=relid) as row, sess:

    ...[manipulation code]...
```

Particularly as python already supports sequence unpacking in most other contexts (`for`, list comprehension, normal assignment, etc...).

Experimenting with things <strike>like trying to put `row, sess` is invalid</strike> [confuses the sublime text syntax highlighter](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues/1467), and I'm apparently not smart enough to understand if this is just flat out not possible from the formal grammar definition.

Is there a better way then having to manually unpack the tuple?

Comment: "trying to put `row, sess` in parenthesis didn't seem to work" — Can you elaborate on that?  Based on my reading of the grammar, that should work.

Comment: What you want to do [works just fine](https://repl.it/repls/FirmNeighboringRobodoc). If your code doesn't work, you've done something wrong, and you need to show us the code so we can fix it, not just tell us that it exists and for some reason doesn't work.

Comment: @jwodder - see edit. Turns out I'm just a fool.

Comment: @abarnert - see edit. Turns out I'm just a fool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrrgh, so I got stymied by syntax highlighting.

You *can* do:

```
with self.row_sess_context(dbid=relid) as (row, sess):
```

but it breaks the native sublime-text python highlighting, so I *thought* it wasn't valid.

See: https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues/1467

At least I got a bug report out of it.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to write doesn't work:

```
with self.row_sess_context(dbid=relid) as row, sess:
```

… because a `with` statement can take multiple context managers and bind each one's context value, so you're asking it to enter `self.row_sess_context(dbid=relid)` and bind its value as `row`, and enter `sess` and ignore its value. Since `sess` probably isn't a context manager, this is an error.

But if you just parenthesize the unpackables, it does exactly what you want:

```
with self.row_sess_context(dbid=relid) as (row, sess):
```

Since it's impossible to demonstrate with your incomplete code fragment, here's a minimal example that anyone can run:

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def ctx():
    yield (1, 2)

with ctx() as (x, y):
    print(x, y)
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out literally about 30 seconds after clicking "post". Derp.

Comment: Don't feel too bad. I'm pretty sure I argued with Nick Coghlan that nobody would ever make this mistake when he first proposed it, and then made exactly this mistake myself shortly after the next version of Python came out…